# Props being mutated in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to vue and I am getting this error, I am not sure if I am passing the props right and executing it well in the other component. I will explain in details what I am trying to acheive.

I am hiding a component on click on this page and showing another element on click interchangeably  here.

**I have read a couple of solutions but I do not understand how I'm exactly suppose to fix it**

```
 <div v-if="hidden" class="orderSummary">
      <div class="orderSummary__container">
        <h2 class="orderSummary__header">Order Summary</h2>
 <button @click="showForm()" class="total__button">Continue</button>
 <PaymentForm v-if="!hidden" :hidden="hiddenMode" />
</div>
</div>
```

```
 methods: {
    showForm() {
      if (this.subTotal > 1) {
        this.hidden = false;
      }
    }
  },
```

now in the Payment Form component I need to hide the component and make the other appear also, i want to do this by passing props.
This is my code

```
 <div class="payForm">
      <div @click="hideForm()" class="PayForm__icon">
        <backIcon class="icon" />
        <span class="PayForm__icon-text">Go &nbsp; back</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

```
props: ["base_amount", "value_added_tax", "hiddenMode"],

methods: {
    submit() {
      const data = {
        name: this.name,
        
      };
      
    },

    hideForm() {
     this.hiddenMode = true;
    }
  },
```

I'm getting the error below, what do I do

```
Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "hiddenMode"
```

Comment: You can either emit an event to the parent or use the `computed` property in the child

Answer (score 0):

Don't make hiddenMode a prop; set it to state through data:

```
//parent
props: ["base_amount", "value_added_tax"],


data() {
   return {
        hiddenMode: false
   }
},
...
```

edit:

You should also move hideForm() to the parent component and instead bind to PaymentForm's onlick:

```
@click="$emit('clicked')"
```

then in the parent component bind hideForm to the clicked emit:

```
<PaymentForm v-if="!hidden" :hidden="hiddenMode" @clicked="hideForm"/>
```

Note: the $emit doesn't have to be called "clicked" you can name it anything

Comment: what of my "hideForm" function, I need to hide this component and display on the other page.

Comment: I see what you mean, I updated my answer. You need to move hiddenMode and hideForm up into the parent and use $emit in the payment component.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`.sync`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#sync-Modifier) modifier. This way the child component does not modify the property directly. So the parent would be

`<PaymentForm v-if="!hidden" :hidden-mode.sync="hiddenMode" />`

and the child would be

```
hideForm() {
  this.$emit('update:hiddenMode', true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a logical problem here. If hidden is false then the first DIV and children including PaymentForm are not existing.
If hidden is true the PaymentForm not showing too because you have a `<PaymentForm v-if="!hidden"`

Second, your PaymentForm has a hiddenMode prop and you don't set it in the parent vue. You should have `:hiddenMode="hidden"` and not `:hidden="hiddenMode"`

For you hideForm function use $emit

```
  this.$emit('update:hiddenMode', true);
```